# Check for multiple values within CASE statement

Tags: oracle, case

How do I check for multiple things in my case statement without writing multiple lines, checking for each case.

I tried this and it's very ugly.

I want something clean like below but can't make it work.

```
  select CASE 
           WHEN (UPPER(NAME) IN ('%AVG%', '%AVERAGE%') AND 
                FORMATTED_ENTRY NOT IN('<', '>')) 
           THEN FORMATTED_ENTRY  END actual_avg
    FROM VALUES_TABLE
```

Comment: you can't do a wildcard % without a like within an IN they have to be separate.  THis may be possible using regular expressions however.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm

Comment: Why doesn't that approach work - are you getting an error, or wrong results? What you've shown looks OK, except you're using wildcards in the `IN` - which you an replace with `OR`. Maybe showing your 'multiple lines' version would clarify the issue you're having?

Comment: Yes, you cannot use wildcards(`%`) in the `IN` clause, but what you can do is to use `regexp_like()` regular expression function(Oracle 10g and up). [Here is a small example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/31649).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want wildcard matching on those percent signs:

```
CASE WHEN (
           ( UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%AVG%' OR UPPER(NAME) LIKE '%AVERAGE%' )
           AND FORMATTED_ENTRY NOT IN('<', '>')
          ) 
         THEN FORMATTED_ENTRY  END actual_avg
```